# How do I create a group containing multiple groups of images in fabricjs

Tags: image, loading, fabricjs

I need to dynamically add groups of multiple groups of images to the canvas, these "multi-group" will react differently depending on which of he contained groups has been dragged over by another group. I need these multi-groups to be able to be selected, rotated and dragged around the screen.

Ive chosen to use FabricJS and create images using fabric.Image.fromURL, manipulate, then add them to the canvas in a callback function. To add multiple images to a group, you nest more images in cascading callback functions as shown in [this tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/)

I cant find a way to get a reference to a group of images created this way so I can add another group of images. Declaring a variable before any calls to fabric.Image.fromURL and trying to assign a reference to a created image doesnt work. The only way Ive got something working is a horrible desparate hack of adding such a group to the canvas then setting it as the active object then creating a new group and adding that active object to the group, this is soooo wrong and I dont think it will work for 3 groups. Heres my last coding attempt;

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('images/icon_station.png', function(img) {
    var img1 = img;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('images/icon_curve.png', function(img) {
        img.set({left: 64,top: 64,angle: -90});
        var img2 = img;
        fabric.Image.fromURL('images/icon_curve.png', function(img) {
            var img3 = img;
            var tile_loop = new fabric.Group([img1, img2, img3]);
            tile_loop.set({left: 0, top: 0, height: 64, width: 64});
            canvas.add(tile_loop).setActiveObject(tile_loop);
        });
    });
});
fabric.Image.fromURL('images/icon_station.png', function(img) {            
    img.set({left: 64,top: 64});           
    var img1 = img;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('images/icon_straight.png', function(img) {
        img.set({left: 64,top: 64});
        var img2 = img;
        fabric.Image.fromURL('images/icon_curve.png', function(img) {
            img.set({left: 64,top: 64});
            var img3 = img;
            var tile_loop = new fabric.Group([img1,img2,img3,canvas.getActiveObject()]);
            tile_loop.set({left: 128, top: 128, height: 128, width: 128});
            canvas.add(tile_loop);
        });
    });
});
```

The only other way Ive seen is to load images into html tags and create them in fabric from the tags, like this

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-img');
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {left: 100,top: 100});
canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

but that seems like a last resort work around, I would prefer to load images up directly in fabricjs.

Ive tried to do this in Phaser but it doesnt do groups of groups, Fabric has all the other stuff I need so I would like to stay with it, its a shame it does these weird ways of handling images.

Any help is much appreciated, if all else fails Ill use the last resort, it would be great to  find a clever correct way.

I created an example in JSFiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/d7bjbpfb/